# Request Headers don't come through on Production but do when testing locally

Tags: laravel, apache, api-design

I am using Laravel and Apache. When I am testing locally and hitting my API against 127.0.0.1:8000 I am able to get a specific header I add with POSTMAN. When I switch over to production and try to hit my API test.dev.com my Headers don't come through with the request anymore. Is it possible Apache is removing the Headers or is this an issue with what I am doing in Laravel? I am checking the Headers for my APP_KEY saved in my dot env file with AuthKey in my Http/Middleware.

Comment: the change is possibly from server(apache/nginx/...) / provider / VPN

Comment: Thanks, apache is probably removing the headers since I am able to get request parameters fine. @N69S Do you know of any docs the deal with apache doing this and how to fix?

Comment: I think this will be the answer to my solution, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php